# java servlets No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/crud_db

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc

This is a simple .jsp signup form:-

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Register page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form name="registration" method="post" action="RegServlet">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gender</td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><label for="male">Male</label>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"><label for="female">Female</label></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>E-mail</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="age"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="address"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>State</td>
                        <td><select name="state">
                                <option value="chd">Chd</option>
                                <option value="punjab">Punjab</option>
                                <option value="haryana">Haryana</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td>Skills</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="java">Java
                <input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="php">Php
                <input type="checkbox" name="skill" value="wordpress">Wordpress</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><button type="submit" value="submit">submit</button>

        </table></form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my servlet file:

```
package org.servlet.java;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class RegServlet extends HttpServlet {

    StringBuilder csvSkills = new StringBuilder();

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet RegServlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet RegServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException 

    {
        processRequest(request, response);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
           out.println("---------servelt post method-----------------");

        String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
        String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
        String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String skill[] = {"dfdsf","sdfsdfds","dsff"};//request.getParameterValues("skill");
        String state = request.getParameter("state");
        String age = request.getParameter("age");
        String address = request.getParameter("address");

           for (String skills : skill) {
            if (csvSkills.length() > 0) {
                csvSkills.append(",");
                csvSkills.append(skills);
            }
            String csvSkill = csvSkills.toString();

            GetsSets sets = new GetsSets();
            sets.setLname(lname);
            sets.setFname(fname);
            sets.setEmail(email);
            sets.setSkill(csvSkill);
            sets.setAge(age);
            sets.setPassword(password);
            sets.setState(state);
            sets.setAddress(address);
            sets.setGender(gender);
            try {
                DBManager.Insert(sets);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

These are my Connection Manager:

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    private static ConnectionManager instance = null;

    private final String USERNAME = "root";
    private final String PASSWORD = "root";
    private final String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/crud_db";


    private Connection conn = null;

    private ConnectionManager() {

    }

    public static ConnectionManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ConnectionManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private boolean openConnection() {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (conn == null) {
            if (openConnection()) {
                System.out.println("connection openned HE EH EH EHE HEE HE");
                return conn;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return conn;
    }
    public void close(){
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        conn = null;
    }
}
```

This is my DBManager:

```
package org.servlet.java;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class DBManager {

private static Connection conn=ConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();

public static void Insert(GetsSets set)throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException{
  // Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    String sql = "INSERT INTO register (fname,lname,gender,state,email,password,age,address,skill) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";   
     PreparedStatement pstmt= conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     pstmt.setString(1, set.getFname());
     pstmt.setString(2, set.getLname());
    pstmt.setString(3, set.getGender());
     pstmt.setString(4, set.getState());
     //pstmt.setString(5, set.getCity());
    pstmt.setString(5, set.getEmail());
     pstmt.setString(6, set.getPassword());
     pstmt.setString(7, set.getAge());
     pstmt.setString(8, set.getAddress());
     pstmt.setString(9, set.getSkill());
     pstmt.executeUpdate();
     ConnectionManager.getInstance().close();   // to avoid memory lekage
     }
}
```

Stuck here since last 4 hours.... Mind is blocked now.... Need serious help.... 
This is my First servlet example. Page gets redirected, but then it show error in log file  "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/crud_db"
Plz... Help me..........

Comment: If you google that you should get tons of answers and examples on how to fix this.

Comment: did that....  But don't know why didn't found a suitable answer....

Comment: I hope you missed the port number private final String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/crud_db"; Instead it should be private final String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crud_db";

Answer (score 1):

You have missed this code for loading the driver

```
try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

        }
```

Here "org.postgresql.Driver" may be different if you are using other database

Answer (score 0):

mysql-connector-java-jar should be set on the class path. Please check whether the mentioned jar is present in the class path

Comment: Also check whether that jar is placed in the lib folder of tomcat